# Oracle APEX Application Builder's Search Application Functionality

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

Does anyone know how "Search Application" functionality of Oracle APEX's Application Builder implemented. Are there any APIs that developer's can take advantage? I would like to search for a text in apex application source code.

Any suggestions would be of great help.

[image: Application Builder --> Search Application]

[image: Search Dialog]

Answer (score 0):

You can use Oracle Text to help find and markup results for hetergenous data. Here is my old session on the topic, and I've seen a few others around.
https://www.slideshare.net/ScottWesley/oracle-text-in-apex

Oracle's learning library:
https://apexapps.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=44785:24:6694877585964::NO:RP,24:P24_CONTENT_ID,P24_PREV_PAGE:8961,2

The results probably use the detail view of an IR, or a template defined for a classic report. In 5.2 the search feature uses different technology - Spotlight search.

APEX metadata can be found in a number of dictionary views, depending on what source code you're looking for. See apex_dictionary view.

*Update Oct 2018*

Daniel H has created a new plugin, leveraging the spotlight search functionality available in the 18.x app builder.

https://github.com/Dani3lSun/apex-plugin-spotlight